# vuejs binding items dynamically

Tags: vue.js

I've got basic select that I want bind to array. I use vuetify, but this problem is universal.

```
<v-select
v-bind:items="physicianListSpeciality"
>
</v-select>
```

now I want to use the same select to many arrays, depend on `offer.person` value that could be physician, nurse etc.

```
data: {
offer.person: "physician" //or offer.person: "nurse"
}
```

For example for `physician` I want to bind `physicianListSpeciality`
For `nurse` I want to bind `nurseListSpeciality`,
etc.

I tried to make something like:

```
<v-select
v-bind:items="`${offer.person}`ListSpeciality"
>
</v-select>
```

or

```
v-bind:items="[offer.person +'ListSpeciality']"
```

none of them seems to work for me.
How should correct my code to make this work? Should I use some kind of computed or there is another way to do it?

Comment: v-bind:items="offer.person +'ListSpeciality'"

Comment: @samayo this gives `[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got String.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends what scope you're.
If you're working in the window scope, you would just call the var using `window[offer.person + 'ListSpeciality']`.

If we're in the component scope, and the getters / data 'nurseListSpeciality' exists then you could call it from the `this` context like so: `this[offer.person + 'ListSpeciality']` where offer.person would be 'nurse'.

Another alternative would be to do something like that:
Taking your example with your item's data

```
data() {
  return {
    jobs: {
      nurse: [
        'nurse item A',
        'nurse item B',
        'nurse item C',
      ],
      physician: [
        'physician item A',
        'physician item B',
        'physician item C',
      ],
    },
  };
}
```

Then you could just get the items like so:

```
// offer.person = 'nurse';
<v-select
  :items="jobs[offer.person]"
>
</v-select>
```

Comment: I've doing spa. This should work, but I don't want to make changes of my array, beacuse they are arrays of objects and are used many times in my app already. My intention was to make simply change into :items prop

Comment: solution with `this.[offer.person + 'ListSpeciality']` works for me! Thank you for help

Comment: @gileneusz Alright, then as in my edited answer, you could simply call `this[offer.person + 'ListSpeciality']`since just passing the string concatenation wont work. You need to call the variable to bind the array in the :items property.